# Decoding what these Valgrind debugger memory errors mean within my code

Tags: c, arrays, memory, segmentation-fault, valgrind

Fairly new student to c here. Just finished setting up a Linux subsytem so i can run Valgrind for debugging purposes. I'm working on an assignment that requires multiple arrays of strings, and organized storing of those values. I believe the logic of my code is sound, however when running it immediately exits the process leaving no time for me to even input the n number of times the program will run. I believe this is a segmentation fault, and downloaded valgrind to pinpoint the problem. However i am having trouble understanding what these error messages mean. It seems there is only one or two errors, but i could be wrong. I may need to use dynamic memory functions (malloc, calloc...) to make it work, but i am even more of a beginner when it comes to memory allocation and am not sure even where to start. Any advice on what my valgrind errors mean, or how i should go about dynamically allocating memory would be greatly appreciated :)

Any additional information anyone needs, feel free to ask.

Ive eliminated any error that showed up that i knew could be solved. Now only these two remain. I believe it has something to do with a segmentation fault or not allocating memory correctly, but i am not sure.

Here is my current code. It may be a bit messy, or have bad whitespace. I am also open to criticism on my coding style :)

```
    int main() {
int n, i, j = 0, k, m, p, flag, key, count;
char choiceUQ, choiceSS[100];
char nameTemp[100], printStu[n][100];
char stuName[n][100], stuSym[n][n][100];        

scanf("%d", &n); //Scan in n number of times u or q will run

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) { //initialize all symptoms to be null for later if statement.
    for(k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        strcpy (stuSym[k][i], "");
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    strcpy(nameTemp, "");
    scanf("%c", &choiceUQ);
    if(choiceUQ == 'u') { 
        flag = 0; //set flag to 0, will be changed if name is already in database.
        scanf("%s", nameTemp);
        for(k = 0; k < i; k++) { //for loop checks if name is already in database.
            if(nameTemp == stuName[k]) { 
                flag = 1; //sets flag if name is in database.
                for(m = 0; m < i; m++) { //checks for next available string array spot for symptoms.
                    if(stuSym[m][k] == "")
                       scanf("%s", stuSym[m][k]);
                }
            }
        }
        if(flag == 0) { //checks for set flag, if no flag is set, it is a new name, so symptom spot will always be 0.
           strcpy(stuName[i], nameTemp);
           scanf("%s", stuSym[0][i]);
        }
}
    if(choiceUQ == 'q') {
        scanf("%s", choiceSS); //checks for input student or symptom, and executes code related to it.
        if(choiceSS == "student") {
            scanf("%s", nameTemp);
            for(k = 0; k < i; k++) { //searches for student name in database
                if(nameTemp == stuName[k]) 
                    key = k;
            }
            for(m = 0; m < i; m++) {
                printf("%s\n", stuSym[m][key]); //prints all symptoms that student has reported
            }
        }
        if(choiceSS == "symptom") {
            count = 0; //initialize count of symptoms at 0
            scanf("%s", nameTemp);
            for(k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                for(m = 0; m < i; m++) {
                   if(nameTemp == stuSym[m][k]) { //nested for loops lead to if loop to check if each student has the given symptom
                      strcpy(printStu[count], stuName[k]);
                      count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(p = 0; p < count; p++) { //prints all students copied into printStu array
                printf("%s", printStu[p]);
            }
        }
    }      
}

return 0;
```

}

The error i am getting in valgrind is shown below

```
==4540== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block

==4540== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4540==    at 0x108B9C: main (santos_pandemic2.c:12)


==4540== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==4540==    at 0x4EB7EC0: __isoc99_scanf (isoc99_scanf.c:27)

^[[A

==4540== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4540==    at 0x108C20: main (santos_pandemic2.c:14)

==4540== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4540==    at 0x109115: main (santos_pandemic2.c:20)

==4540== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4540==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4540==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 4,096 bytes allocated

==4540== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: What do you expect `char stuName[n][100], stuSym[n][n][100];` to do when `n` hasn't been initialized yet?

Comment: I just figured if it wasn't used until n was set it wouldn't cause problems. Just not sure what to set the max array value at, if the max will be a user input. Would declaring it after the scanf cause more problems than it would fix?

Comment: If you are using gcc, compile with -Wall -Werror flags; you will get compilation errors when you use uninitialized variables which is a lot better than trying to debug them.  Always compile with those two flags set

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", choiceSS);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input format conversion specifiers'.  In this case, any value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.   2) when using '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte.  This also avoid any possible buffer overflow and attendant Undefined Behavior

Comment: when posting code, please post code that compiles (even if it has errors)  The posted code is missing the two statements: `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string.h>`

Comment: place this: `scanf("%d", &n);` before those statements that use 'n' to declare array.  This is using the C feature: `Variable Length Arrays` (VLA)

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%c", &choiceUQ);
    if(choiceUQ == 'u') { `  What if the user types a 'U'?  Suggest `#include <ctype.h>`  and `if( tolower( choiceUQ ) == 'u' )`

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%c", &choiceUQ);`  How is the user to know that they need to enter a `u` or a `q`?  Suggest outputting a prompt informing the user of their allowed choices.  and suggest the code have code for when neither a `u` nor a `q` is entered by the user

Comment: regarding; `if(nameTemp == stuSym[m][k]) {`   character arrays cannot be compared with a `==`.   this is actually comparing the addresses.  Strongly suggest using `if( strcmp( nameTemp, stuSym[m][k] ) == 0 ) {`

Comment: Regarding: `strcpy (stuSym[k][i], "");` this sets the first character in the buffer of 100 characters to '\0' and does not effect the other 99 characters. suggest when declaring the array use: `char stuSym[n][n][100] = {'\0'};` as this will set the whole array to '\0' Then you can/should eliminate the nested for() loops that are currently trying to clear the arrays

Answer (score 2):

```
char nameTemp[100], printStu[n][100];
char stuName[n][100], stuSym[n][n][100];
```

You use the uninitialised value n to declare these arrays. C isn't smart enough to figure out that it should declare the arrays after you give n a value using scanf.

Since you want these array's to be dynamically allocated (using the value you get from scanf), I would suggest using malloc to allocate memory for them. Or look into 'variable length arrays' and how you can make them work.